# SQL Get multiple values into one column separated by comma

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help on this SQL Query. Node is a table of products and each product has n images on table field_data_field_images. I need to select all of those image file names into one column separated by comma (as example "image1.jpg, image2.jpg" and so on). So first I need to get all of the image ID's from field_data_field_images and then get the file names itself from file_managed.

```
SELECT node.*,
file_managed.filename,
field_data_field_product_code.field_product_code_value,
FROM node

LEFT JOIN field_data_field_images ON node.nid = field_data_field_images.entity_id
LEFT JOIN file_managed ON field_data_field_images.field_images_fid = file_managed.fid

WHERE node.language = 'lt' AND node.type = 'products'
GROUP BY nid
```

Comment: You want to do a Pivot.Have a look at this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Hint: `group_concat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group_concat()`.  The following query also introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT n.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(fm.filename) as filenames
FROM node n LEFT JOIN
     field_data_field_images dfi
     ON n.nid = dfi.entity_id LEFT JOIN
     file_managed fm
     ON dfi.field_images_fid = fm.fid
WHERE n.language = 'lt' AND n.type = 'products'
GROUP BY n.nid
```

Answer (score 1):

IF MS-SQL follow below code:

```
 DECLARE @TableVar TABLE
 (
  nid INT ,
  images NVARCHAR(400)
 );
 INSERT INTO @TableVar
    ( nid ,
      images
    )
    SELECT nid,images

FROM node

LEFT JOIN field_data_field_images 
ON node.nid =     field_data_field_images.entity_id
LEFT JOIN file_managed 
ON field_data_field_images.field_images_fid =   file_managed.fid

WHERE node.language = 'lt' AND node.type = 'products'
GROUP BY nid

SELECT DISTINCT
    nid ,
    STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + images
            FROM    @TableVar AS T
            WHERE   T.nid = T2.nid
          FOR
            XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '') AS images
 FROM   @TableVar T2
 GROUP BY nid ,
    images
```